# AWS elasticsearch access Request signing using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I want to connect to elastic search from Java. Elastic search domain is configured in AWS.  I am using Jest library for this. Currently i have added  my system ip in the elastic search configure access section. So i can access ES endpoint. But this is not the right way of doing it. What are the approches to it ? i know about signing the request but could not find any good reference of how to do it in java. Can anyone give some thoughts ? 
This is how my code looks like

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig.Builder(elasticSearchserverUrl).connTimeout(10000).readTimeout(10000)
            .multiThreaded(true).build());

JestClient client = factory.getObject();
Search.Builder searchBuilder = new Search.Builder(query).addIndices(indices).addType(type);

    try {
        SearchResult result = client.execute(searchBuilder.build());

        List<Hit<String, Void>> hits = result.getHits(String.class);
        for (Hit<String, Void> hit : hits) {
            String log = hit.source;
            System.out.println(log);


        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor

Comment: But that does not seem like a Jest call , isn't it ?

Comment: You'll have to dig further to see what if it helps. It indicates that it was "Originally created to support AWS' Elasticsearch Service using the Jest client." You might also research AWS4Signer in the AWS SDK (example: https://gist.github.com/devilelephant/4ae94f8e9f24b6056733).